# How to define von Neumann natural numbers (newcommand, with for loop)?

Tags: loops, variable, renewcommand

How can I define a new command, `\natset[1]{#1}`, which gives an output as follows?

[image: Example of usage/output]

(∅ = \varnothing); intended use is in ***math-mode***, e.g. `$\natset[1]{#1}$`. The braces are the things one usually gets with `$\{ \}$`.

---

Living in TeX-ic pseudo-code land, I would perhaps do:

```
\newcommand{\natset}[1]{%
    iter_set := \varnothing
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}{%
        temp_set := iter_set∪{iter_set}
        iter_set := temp_set
    \return iter_set}
```

- How can I convert such loops into LaTeX (to compile with `pdflatex`)?

I have tried various combinations, `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand` and `\noexpand`/`\expandafter` business which gave nothing reasonable.

The basic preamble and test cases:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} %for \text inside $$ $$
\usepackage{amssymb} %for \varnothing
%\usepackage{xifthen} %maybe needed
\usepackage{tikz} %for-loop

%definition here
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\natset}[1]{#1}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

    $$\text{0 gives}\qquad \natset{0}$$
    $$\text{1 gives}\qquad \natset{1}$$
    $$\text{2 gives}\qquad \natset{2}$$
    $$\text{8 gives}\qquad \natset{8}$$
    
\end{document}
```

I have additional plans with this command in the future (like adding optional arguments, changing style to Zermelo's naturals, etc.). The von Neumann stuff is to hopefully get me started. Of course, answers of any complexity are welcome, but simpler answers (syntactically) will probably be most helpful. Or complicated answers with some additional comments.

Comment: Are the braces typeset braces or TeX groupings?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes They are meant to be in math-mode, so I guess typeset braces, i.e. ``$\{ \}$`` things. Will edit into question to be more precise, thank you for the remark.

Comment: I apologise for not being active at the moment on this issue. Hopefully, I can check the answers by this weekend.

Comment: You have several active questions, if I recall.  That's a good thing!

Answer (score 27):

I think its more natural to use recursion than a loop, something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\newcommand\nnatset[1]{%
 \ifnum#1=0 \varnothing \else
 \ifnum#1>1 \nnatset{\numexpr#1-1},\{\fi\nnatset{\numexpr#1-1}\ifnum#1>1 \}\fi
 \fi}
\newcommand\natset[1]{\ifnum#1>0\{\fi\nnatset{#1} \ifnum#1>0\}\fi}

\begin{document}

$\natset{0}$

$\natset{1}$

$\natset{2}$

$\natset{3}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: It could be interesting to explain a little the necessity of the `\if` for the recursion calls by developing, for example, the expansion of `\nateset{2}`.

Comment: @projetmbc er yes but if it wasn't midnight it must have been possible not to repeat the test in both wrappers, I may look to refactor before documenting it. As I commented under Steven's answer most of that complication is to get  the cosmetic  ∅ rather than {} at the end of the recursion.

Answer (score 13):

The interesting thing about this solution is that I actually build it up as TeX groups of empty groups (that is, according to the actual von Neumann grouping placed in the macro `\z`).  Then I use `tokcycle` to interpret the catcode-1,2 groups in a typesettable way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle,amssymb}
\newcommand{\natset}[1]{\def\z{}\natsetaux{#1}}
\newcommand\natsetaux[1]{%
  \ifnum\numexpr#1\relax>0\relax
    \edef\z{\z{\z}}%
    \natsetaux{#1-1}%
  \else
    \expandedtokcyclexpress{{\z}}%
  \fi}
\Groupdirective{%
  \if\relax#1\relax\varnothing\else
  \ifnum\tcdepth>1\relax,\fi\{\processtoks{#1}\}\fi}
\begin{document}

$\natset 0$

$\natset 1$

$\natset 2$

$\natset 3$

$\natset 4$
\end{document}
```

[image]

To give a better idea, for `\natset 3`, the value of `\z` is catcode 1 and 2 braces (not typesetable) in the `\detokenize`d pattern of

[image]

and then, `tokcycle` is fed the expanded `{\z}` and executes the `\Groupdirective` every time a brace group is encountered in the input stream.  Inside the `\Groupdirective`, the term `#1` refers to the contents of the group.  If it is an empty group, I typeset `\varnothing`.  Otherwise, I place a comma as needed and recommit the non-empty group contents to the token cycle, all the while placing typeset braces around the result of that.   The resulting typeset gives

[image]

I would only add, in closing, that the above implementation of `\natsetaux` was written for ease of comprehension.  However, it uses up stack as part of the recursion, as the `\fi`s build up and are only released upon final completion.  That is not a problem for small arguments to `\natset`.  However, if one were to want this for large numbers of expansions, it would be best to reimplement `\natsetaux` in a way that finishes itself prior to the next recursion call.  Here is such a way:

```
\newcommand\natsetaux[1]{\tctestifnum{#1>0}{\edef\z{\z{\z}}%
     \expandafter\natsetaux\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1}}
    {\expandedtokcyclexpress{{\z}}}}
```

Comment: varnothing (empty set) more conventional than phi:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks.  I will fix.

Comment: I actually prefer the `{}` notation for empty set, in both your version and mine the cosmetic display of the empty set as ∅ accounts for more complication than the main recursion

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is exactly the case for me, too.  Not being previously familiar with the notation, it took a while to reach the logical conclusion that `{} \equiv \varnothing`, in order to make it work.

Comment: You mean this isn't how you think of the natural numbers, building up from a logical framework that starts with the axioms of set theory, and nothing else?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle LOLOLOL!!!  No, it wasn't until I was 50 years old that I had the "profound" revelation that the reason a circle had 360 degrees in it is because 360 is divisible by so many integers, (1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,15,18,20,24,30,36,40,45,60,72,90,120,180,360),  that pure fractions of a circle could be readily established with whole numbers of degrees.  Back then, the world ran on fractions, not decimals.  I'm sure the irrational desire to establish the rationality of pi had much to do with slicing the circle into ever increasing divisions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Anyhow, the only set of empty sets that has practical significance to me is the set of refrigerators in the house, each of which has the empty set of beer bottles in it.  Only then does set theory become real to me.

Comment: :-) you can model the natural numbers in anything that has a distinct element (we can call zero) and a successor function that always returns a new not previously returned element. All other properties of the integers can be derived from that.   This shows you can model zero and successor in set theory by zero ={} and succ(S) = S union {S}  that is, the successor of the set S the set consisting of the elements of S and S itself.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is beginning to sound like mathematical induction.

Answer (score 1):

A crude LaTeX3 solution:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_natset_tmpa_int

\NewDocumentCommand \natset { m }
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_natset_tmpa_int { #1 }

    \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_natset_tmpa_int } = { 0 }
      {
        \varnothing
      }
      {
        \{ \varnothing
        \int_step_inline:nnn { 1 } { \l_natset_tmpa_int - 1 }
          {
            , \natset { ##1 }
          }
        \}
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
0 &= \natset{0} \\
1 &= \natset{1} \\
2 &= \natset{2} \\
3 &= \natset{3} \\
4 &= \natset{4} \\
5 &= \natset{5}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]